# Spreading observable and then grouping it back together

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

**PROBLEM**

I need to create operation like this:

`get all elements from DB -> send call to API that these elements are marked as read -> save status of read elements`

I'm trying to make a good chain with RxJava and I want to:

1. Gather data from DB
2. Created Observable with a `List<Integer>` with remoteIds
3. Call API on these elements
4. Gather all the responses and pass it as `List<Integer>`
5. Save the responses

Problem is the spreading and grouping from points 3. 4. im not sure how to make such a chain. And as you can see below I'm stuck on point 3. with my code because I don't know how to gather the data for each request. Is there some kind of transformation that might be useful in my case?

**ACTUAL PROGRESS aka CODE**

```
 sub = getDb()
            .createQuery(DbContract.Notification.TABLE_NAME, sql, String.valueOf(NOTIFICATION_UNREAD))
            .map(new CursorListMapper<>(new NotificationPersistenceModel()))
            .map(new Func1<List<DataNotification>, Observable<List<Integer>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<Integer>> call(List<DataNotification> notifications) {
                    List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataNotification notification : notifications) {
                        ids.add(notification.getRemoteId());
                    }

                    return Observable.just(ids);
                }
            })
            .subscribe();
```

**EDIT**

- List of `Observables` seemed like a bad idea - changed to `Observable<List<Integer>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mapping to `Observable<List<Integer>>`, map to `List<Integer>` and then use `Observable.from()` to convert the list to an Observable emitting each list element. Next you just flatMap that to an Api call. Here's an example

```
getDb()
        .createQuery(...)
        .map(...)
        .map(...) // map to List<Integer>
        .flatMap(new Func1<List<Integer>, Observable<List<Response>>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<List<Response>> call(List<Integer> integers) {
                return Observable.from(list)
                        .flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Response>>() {
                           @Override
                           public Observable<Response> call(Integer integer) {
                                return api.call(integer);
                            }
                        })
                        .toList();
            }
        })
```

than you can continue mapping/flatMapping to whatever you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks mate that was the missing part! Did not know about `toList` method - that helped a lot.